# Amperian loop for different situations

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Why are amperian loops always taken as circles? What if we take it as a triangle or rectangle? Give an example by taking amperian loop as rectangle for current carrying straight wire and derive equation for magnetic field? How will the equation change?

Answer (score 3):

An Amperian loop can be *any closed path*. Ampere's law is true for *any closed path*.
$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} = \mu_0 I_{\rm enc} $$

Whether the law is useful or not depends on whether you are able to easily calclulate the LHS (the closed line integral of the B-field around the loop), and the RHS (the total current passing through that loop).

It is usually the LHS that determines what shape of loop you should *choose*. The ideal case would be where the B-field is *either* parallel or perpendicular to the loop line element, all the way around the loop, and/or of constant magnitude. That makes the LHS easy to calculate.

In the case of a long wire, there is symmetry around the axis of the wire, such that the B-field curves around the the wire and thus is constant in magnitude at a given distance from the wire and will always be parallel to the line element on a circular path. Thus
$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} \rightarrow 2\pi r B_r\ .$$

There are examples where non-circular loops are used. The most well known would be the long solenoid. A *rectangular* loop placed with one of its straight sides along the axis of the solenoid and its opposite side *outside* the solenoid is most useful here, since the B-field in the solenoid is directed along the axis and the B-field outside the solenoid is $\sim 0$. Thus
$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} \rightarrow L B_z\ , $$
where $L$ is the length of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I would want to complement the above answer with a solid correlation with Gaussian surfaces from Electrostatics.

But to answer your question independently, we are not wishing for the $B$ field to be circles.
It just circulates!

Acc to the Ampere's law.
$$\oint \bf{B} \cdot \bf{dl} = \mu I$$
In English, it means "*magnetic flux circulates around permeated current*".

Coming to Amperian loops, its a "technique" in physics than anything.

We want to solve things and with the least effort (right?).
Here, it means to find that flux our current is inducing.
AND We have this fantastic equation that says - it circulates around our current.

What if - we declared a loop (contour) which naturally falls with the induced flux so that we could pull the $B$ field out of the integral?

$$B (\oint dl) = \mu I$$

To exactly answer the rectangle amperian loop case, it is like "squaring the circle". I can imagine a current flow in a square cross-section conductor where current intensity decreases towards the edges and diminishes at vertices. It makes a soft square in flux shape. ($a$ - side of this square).
$$B \oint dl = \mu I \Rightarrow B(4a) = \mu I$$